# Listview in layout which should be scrollable

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have a problem, I have a long layout so I need it will be scrollable. But I need two listview in it. I have made using linearlayout and in forcycle I add a items in it. But I have lost all functions what listview offers and I want to use them.

Do anybody knows, how looks like "events" view in facebook app? It looks like there are a lot of listviews (birthdays, events, ...) and whole view is scrollable. I need something like this.

Thank you for ansver. :)

**EDIT:** There is my xml (There are two LinearLayouts: @+id/passengersList and @+id/discussionList and I want use ListViews instead):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/travelDetailScroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#f8ffe1"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/travelId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/waypoints"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/travelMap"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/waypoints"
            android:contentDescription="@string/travel_detail" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driver"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/waypoints"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/travelMap"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/car"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/driver"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/travelMap"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/waypoints"
            android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_price"
            android:layout_below="@+id/car"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/travelMap"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/travel_price" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/car"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_price" 
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_seats"
            android:layout_below="@+id/car"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/price"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/travel_seats" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seats"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/car"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_seats"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/buttonsLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_travel_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/travel_login" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_travel_logout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/travel_logout"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/buttonsRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonsLeft" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_travel_edit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/travel_edit"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_travel_watch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/travel_watch"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_travel_unwatch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/travel_unwatch"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttons"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driverTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="@string/driver_title" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/driverInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/driverTitle"
            android:background="#f8ffe1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/driverPhoto"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/driverName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/driverPhoto"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/driverEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/driverName"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/driverPhoto"
                android:textColor="#999999"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/driverPhone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/driverEmail"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/driverPhoto"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="14sp" /> 

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/passengersInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/driverInfo"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/passengersTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="@string/passengers_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noPassengers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/passengersTitle"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="@string/no_passengers"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/passengersList"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/passengersTitle"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/discussion"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/passengersInfo"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/discussionTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="@string/discussion_title" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/discussionList"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/discussionTitle"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/addMessageLink"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:textColor="#8ec83e"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/discussionList"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/add_message" />

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/newMessageLayout" 
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/addMessageLink"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:paddingTop="7dp"
                  android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                  android:visibility="gone">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/newMessage"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:hint="@string/new_message"
                    android:layout_weight="3" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addMessage"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:hint="@string/send_message"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/waypointsDetail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/discussion"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/waypointsTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="@string/waypoints_title" />

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/waypointsList" 
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/waypointsTitle"
                  android:orientation="vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/waypointsSummary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/waypointsList" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: please show your xml layout. what you had tried so far..

Comment: *"I have a long layout so I need it will be scrollable"* That's a bad Android app design. Think on how to organize your interface with activities or tabs and fragments.

Comment: Maybe it isn't good design, but I think, that all informations belong together. It isn't too long and scrolling down is better solution in my opinion than click to show another activity with list. I don't know, maybe you are true, I don't have much experiences with it. But I don't have any idea, how to change design.